# Compile-time function constraints evaluation

Tags: function, rust, constraints, compile-time, const-generics

Is there any way to instruct the compiler to check if a function respects some constraints? For example I would like to use functions `Fn(f64) -> f64` that are guaranteed to evaluate to `-1.0` and `1.0` on the boundaries of a range (e.g. when the argument is `0.0` or `1.0`). I'm aware of [const_guards](https://docs.rs/const_guards/latest/const_guards/) but it seems to me that I would need generic constant functions and I think they're not supported yet. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Can you create a wrapper type that enforces the constraints?

Comment: When you write "check", do you mean "check statically" or "instrument for a dynamic check"?

If the former, no. You'd need a theorem prover or a model-checker for that purpose, and neither is included with the Rust compiler. There are model-checkers for Rust, I haven't checked how powerful they are.

If the latter, there's also nothing built-in, but you can use https://crates.io/crates/contracts or reimplement it yourself fairly easily.

Comment: @Yoric I mean "statically check". For my needs, I don't think a theorem prover will be necessary: if there was a way to use const fn's as generic parameters I would imagine that there will be a way to evaluate that function at compile-time and statically check if the result respects a simple contraint (e.g: f(0) == -1 && f(1) == 1). The check would be very similar to what const_guards crate already does. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I had misunderstood.

I've attempted to implement something but I didn't go very far: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70ef1086ba878345a876fc9629f6c5a9